# ActiveRecord relationship validation with error trying to use 'count'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

I have an Order class, and a Pack class, both using ActiveRecord.  The Order contains Packs.  In my validation of Order, I am testing for the existence of a relationship to one or more Packs.  See the following code:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_packs
  has_many :packs, :through => :order_packs
  validate :my_custom_validation

  def my_custom_validation
    errors.add(:packs, "Your order was empty.") if packs.count < 1
  end
end
```

Seems simple enough, but it doesn't work; `packs.count` is always zero.  So I changed the validation to this code:

```
def my_custom_validation
  errors.add(:packs, "packs is: #{packs}")
  errors.add(:packs, "packs.count is: #{packs.count}")
  errors.add(:packs, "packs.any? is: #{packs.any?}")
end
```

just to see what the deal was, and got this interesting output:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why `count` is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.length` instead of `.count`.

When you use `count` you're actually performing a database query. And because you're doing it on validation, before anything has been saved to the database, you're always getting zero. `length` on the other hand works on the object level and doesn't hit the database at all. So it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks! That was bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

length and size, both are same, and count performs SQL COUNT query,

You should read [count vs length vs size](http://web.archive.org/web/20100210204319/http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size)